# Pentaho Report Designing issue with excel

Tags: excel, report, pentaho

I have created a report in pentaho report designer when i run this report in pdf format it seems to be Ok but when i run this same report in excel format the design get diturbed and cells got merged and data places also get change.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0nRA.png)

I want that each column from pentaho designer come in a single cell of excel.

Comment: what format you using

Comment: While creating an excel use ruler to avoid merged case in excel

Comment: Sir i am new to pentaho kindly explain how to avoid this as i put a lot of effort but failed. Currently i am using pdf format for reporting bui now i have to give the excel format option also but when the report from pentaho change in excel the report behave like above mention link.

Comment: Based on how you create a format.  while creating the  report in --> pentaho report designer try to use ruler concept .

Comment: How we can ujse ruler concept in this?

Comment: Thanks Sir I got the point Thanks Alot

Comment: Thats nice of you

Comment: What happen any issue with my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate format for PDF like A4,A4_Extra and A5. So that you can get what you have selected.There is no specific format for Excel like PDF,So You should use ruler to avoid such merged cells in excel(You have to do separately for excel)